# SQL Server Management Studio decimal column with blank value

Tags: sql-server, decimalformat

I have the couple of columns defined as `decimal(16,2)`.

I would like to leave the value '' (blank) in it.

When I have the select query as

```
CASE 
   WHEN FIELD1 IS NULL THEN ''
   ELSE FIELD1 
END AS FIELD_NAME
```

This will not allowed as the nature of the column.

Could you please help me how can I put a blank value in this column?

Many thanks

Comment: Why keep it as NULL? It kind of fits perfect for this situation. The **worst** thing you could do was change it `varchar()` so that you cold store a blank value. If you don't want to return null, then just return a blank where the value IS NULL to your application. Or handle this in the application itself.

Comment: As you have discovered you can't unless you change the datatype. Honestly this type of thing should be handled in the front end, not in sql server. NULL is the correct value to return from sql for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to leave the values as `NULL`, which is recommended solution, or convert everything to text. The reason for the error is that you cannot return a decimal and a text value in the same column (`''` is a text value).

To convert everything to text and insert the blank value, use the following:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Field1), '')
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments, but if you must do it in SQL you could use a cast in your case statement as per below code.  Better handled in front end though as the below code would mean your final select returns a varchar and not a decimal.  Handled front end, you can return a decimal from SQL and display blank if NULL.

```
create table #temp (thing decimal(16,2))
insert into  #temp (thing) values(NULL)

select 
case when thing IS NULL then '' 
else cast(thing as varchar(5)) end
from #temp
```